# Problem with dynamic route using react-router on ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to implement dynamic route using react-router, I found that it works perfectly on  `npm start` but then I tried on production using  `npm run-script build && serve build` dynamic route seems to be a problem.

When it's an error while trying to load static files(image). Then after a refresh, the whole page seems to be empty, and this error has shown up

[My error after reload (Click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwGgt.png)

```
<Router>
 <Switch>
  <Route path="activity/:id" exact>
   <MyComponent... />
  </Route>
 </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: If you go to 'Network' tab of Inspect, you can see where it's trying to fetch static files and images. You can also see what is being returned. It seems that when it's trying to fetch javascript files, it is receiving HTML/XML. Depending on where you're hosting your site, you may need to change your nginx configuration, or set the `homepage` property in `package.json`

Comment: It's trying to load files with not a normal path(Which I'm using in static route). For chunks files it said ```You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.``` what should i do?

Comment: What's the path where it's trying to load chunk files? It should be returning javascript files, and the "You need to enable JavaScript.." seems like it is returning your index.html when it is asking for the chunk (js) files. This is likely why the page is empty - it cannot load the javascript files.

This could be due to various reasons - if you are using Nginx to host the static files, this could be NGINX configuration needed. If there is a subpath that needs to be added (such as /home/), then this is a package.json configuration under the `homepage` property

Comment: More information about your hosting setup and where it's trying to fetch the files (can be viewed via the Network tab) would be helpful - as this is likely a configuration issue and not an application issue.